# getting data from a model outside of controller rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to get the profile of a selected order (Print order).

My `profiles` table has a `user_id` column and my `prints` table also has a `user_id` column.

The `Profile` and `Print` model `belongs_to :user` model.

Print model:

```
class Print < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :comment, :document
  belongs_to :user
end
```

and, Profile model:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :address, :name, :phone
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :prints
end
```

How do I get the data from the profile for prints according to the user?

Comment: What does your user model look like? Does a user have many profiles or only one?

Comment: Since you have `has_many :prints` on Profile, shouldn't you have `belongs_to :profile` on Print?

Comment: Print and Profile both belong to user. this is probably wrong if Profile is the parent of Print

Answer (score 1, accepted):

suppose you have `print` object & `user has one profile` then

```
print.user.profile
```

Also `Profile` `has_many :prints` which is redundant you can directly used

```
print.profile
```

Comment: For let's say, i want :address field,

i would say print.user.profile.address

same goes for :telephone and :name

yes, the has_may :prints is redundant, which i removed.

Thanks! :)